# Why does Angular 2 use the @ symbol in module names?

Tags: typescript, angular, systemjs

The Angular 2 upgrade guide specifies import statements that look like this:

```
import { UpgradeAdapter } from '@angular/upgrade';
```

(SOURCE: [Angular 2 upgrade guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/upgrade.html))

I have used WebPack as my module loader in the past and have never needed to use the `@` symbol for anything.

Is the `@` symbol special in Angular 2 / SystemJS?

Comment: It's just the new namespace they moved to. Everything is `@angular/something`

Comment: It was a duplicate question. I found out that the "@" symbol means "Edge Version".